# Winrar self extracting SFX fail to launch

Tags: compression, zip, winrar

I created an SFX file (to unzip and launch a program directly) with Winrar which is supposed to be installed in a TEMP folder. I specified to launch "bin/myprogram.exe" after extraction.

When I launch the SFX, I can see that my program is launched but is closed after 0,5 sec. If I go manually to the TEMP folder and launch myself the .exe, verything works very well.

Someone already had the same problem?

My procedure :

I select all the files needed (bin, programData and .ico)
New Archive, set to SFX mode. Under SFX Options button, in Advanced tab :

- Setup : I write bin/myprogram.exe after extraction
- Mode : Decompress in a tempory file

I tried to unzip in a specified folder or in programFile but nothing changed. Same situation

Comment: The '\' solved this ! Thanks ! By the way, how to flag my question "Solved" with no responses but only comment ?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is Windows, simply use `bin\myprogram.exe` instead.